# Magic Mouse Not Scrolling On Brand New Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, mouse, magic-mouse

Just bought a Macbook Pro yesterday and a Magic Mouse today - I love them both but I have just setup the mouse and left and right click work but the slider and scroll do nothing - what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Have you run Software Update on the MacBook Pro to obtain the updated drivers/software for the Magic Mouse?

Comment: I heard it will require a reboot after installing as well ^^

Comment: Yep.  The directions that come with the mouse tell you to do software updates to get the driver too.  When in doubt, please try reading the manual.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Run software update, download mouse update and then adjust mouse settings in system preferences

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had forgotten to remove */System/Library/Extensions/USBOverdrive.kext* from an old USB Overdrive installation.