# magic mouse problem

Tags: macos, mac, magic-mouse

I just bought a magic mouse and connected it to my mac computer. The only things that are working are the right and left click. It is not even bringing up that scrolling thing in system preferences. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: maybe you'll find additional hints here: http://superuser.com/questions/66926/magic-mouse-not-scrolling-on-brand-new-macbook-pro

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run System Update to get the latest driver?

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you running? If not 10.6.2 you won't automatically have the driver. This is correct -- run System Update once the mouse is paired (so System Update is aware of its presence).